# Unable to install ffmpeg in rockylinux 9

Tags: docker, ffmpeg

I am trying to build a **docker** image which is based on `rockylinux9` and includes an installation of the `ffmpeg`.

In my *dockerfile*, I have the following lines for the installation of `ffmpeg`:

```
RUN dnf -y install --nogpgcheck https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-9.noarch.rpm && \
    dnf -y install  ffmpeg
```

and this is somehow failing with the below error when I try to build the image using:
`docker build .`

```
#6 106.4 Error: 
#6 106.4  Problem: package ffmpeg-5.1.2-9.el9.x86_64 requires libavfilter.so.8()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
#6 106.4   - package ffmpeg-5.1.2-9.el9.x86_64 requires libavfilter.so.8(LIBAVFILTER_8)(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
#6 106.4   - package libavfilter-free-5.1.2-6.el9.x86_64 requires librubberband.so.2()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
#6 106.4   - package ffmpeg-libs-5.1.2-9.el9.x86_64 requires librubberband.so.2()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
#6 106.4   - conflicting requests
#6 106.4   - nothing provides ladspa needed by rubberband-3.1.0-2.el9.x86_64
#6 106.4 (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dnf -y install --nogpgcheck https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-9.noarch.rpm &&      dnf -y install ffmpeg --allowerasing]: exit code: 1
```

Can someone help me with this?

I believe I am supposed to install the `ffmpeg` dependencies, but I'm not sure how this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by installing the powertools.

**Reference Links:**

[Rocky Linux Forum - Problem with ffmpeg](https://forums.rockylinux.org/t/install-ffmpeg-problem/4506)

[Rocky Linux Forum - Installing powertools](https://forums.rockylinux.org/t/how-do-i-install-powertools-on-rocky-linux-9/7427)

I used the below statements in dockerfile to achieve this:

```
RUN dnf -y install --nogpgcheck https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-9.noarch.rpm && \
dnf  config-manager --set-enabled crb && \
dnf -y install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score -1):

The FFmpeg package is not available in Rocky Linux 9 base repos, you can install it by adding an extra repo. There are package repos and installation files for different distributions at its [official address](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Comment: Thank you Vineet.


I was able to resolve this issue by installing the powertools as mentioned in the above answer

Comment: Can you please add a code example? I see OP was able to resolve their problem, but this approach might help others, with more detail.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson, edited the answer with the code.